# Gitlab: Set external url to https without certificate

Tags: gitlab

I’m running a gitlab ce server in a docker container with other docker containers on a vserver. I use nginx in another docker container as reverse proxy. Only ports to reverse proxy are forwarded from host and the reverse proxy forwards the requests to the other containers. All request to the reverse proxy to port 80 are redirected to port 443. Reverse proxy manages ssl. Connection from reverse proxy to gitlab is on port 80 and I have no certificate for gitlab container. Now I want to set external_url in gitlab.rb. When I set to http://my.domain.com (it was commented out) it works. When I set to https://my.domain.com, I can’t open the page. I get “to many redirects”. Is it possible to set external_url to https without adding certificates to this container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitLab's [NGINX settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#supporting-proxied-ssl) page explains how to set up this common configuration:

> By default NGINX will auto-detect whether to use SSL if `external_url`
>   contains `https://`. If you are running GitLab behind a reverse proxy,
>   you may wish to terminate SSL at another proxy server or load
>   balancer. To do this, be sure the `external_url` contains `https://` and
>   apply the following configuration to `gitlab.rb`:
>
> ```
> nginx['listen_port'] = 80
> nginx['listen_https'] = false
> ```

It sounds like you may be missing the two additional configuration options above.

Comment: This fixed an issue I was having with infinite redirects from `https://gitlab` to `https://gitlab:443` and back again when running the Docker image behind a reverse proxy.

Comment: As of current date, this is insufficient. I can't provide more detailed response currently, because I can't figure it out. While this scenario of separate nginx and gitlab instance may be considered common, it is also completely common to see hundreds of threads here, on Reddit and Gitlab forums, where people have literally gave up trying. The configs, their constants, labels and use change all the time and the approach presented here is simply not working anymore.

Comment: Just ran into this. From what I can tell, Gitlab wants to know the certificate but then does listen on port 80 and without TLS for my proxy.